# Call to a member function setCookie() on null

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I am trying to finish this middleware in larval that checks to make sure is subscribed to a subscription plan. If the user is not it redirects to the payment page.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::check()){
        if (Auth::user()->subscribed('main')) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return view('payments.payment')->with('user',Auth::user());
        }
    }else{
        abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

I am getting this error with not much luck finding a solution Call to a member function setCookie() on null.

Comment: add the full error script

Answer (score 34):

change

```
return view('payments.payment')
```

to

```
return response()->view('payments.payment')
```

Comment: In case of returning a `view`, this is the correct answer.

Comment: I had the same problem. I was returning a view. This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

The problem is where you are returning `true`. A middleware should return a response-style object, not a boolean.

Since that is your "good" path and you want to proceed with your application logic, you should replace `return true;` with `return $next($request);`

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::check()){
        if (Auth::user()->subscribed('main')) {
            return $next($request);
        }else{
            return view('payments.payment')->with('user',Auth::user());
        }
    }else{
        abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
    }
}
```

On an unrelated recommendation, you can clean up your conditional logic a bit to make your code easier to read/follow:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // If the user is not logged in, respond with a 403 error.
    if ( ! Auth::check()) {
        abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
    }

    // If the user is not subscribed, show a different payments page.
    if ( ! Auth::user()->subscribed('main')) {
        return view('payments.payment')->with('user',Auth::user());
    }

    // The user is subscribed; continue with the request.
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Note that trying to return a view from middleware will still cause the error. It is better to return a redirect response to the route that handles the view instead of trying to return the view itself: `return redirect()->route('route.to.payments.payment');`

Answer (score 5):

return response(view('payments.payment')->with('user',Auth::user()));

Answer (score 3):

i solve by redirect to other route`return redirect()->to('route');`