# Laravel Call to a member function setCookie() on null - when returning controller action from middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

Hello Good Developers,

This is Not a Direct Duplicate of: [Call to a member function setCookie() on null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970172/call-to-a-member-function-setcookie-on-null)
As I am calling a Controller action from Middleware and then in the controller action I am returning View,

Here's My Route from `web.php`

```
Route::get('/end', [EndPageController::class, 'index'])
->name('survey.end')
->middleware('App\Http\Middleware\LegacyEndCheck');
```

Middleware `LegacyEndCheck.php` handle function

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $sjid = $request->input('sjid', false);

    if( empty($sjid) || strlen($sjid) !== 36 ){
        return app()->make(EndLegacyController::class)->index($request); //I have to call EndLegacyController@index here as I can't change URL using redirect route
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Controller `EndLegacyController` `index` action

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $sjid = $request->input('sjid',false);
    $status = $request->input('status',false);
    if( empty($sjid) || empty($status) ){
        $this->status = 5;
        return view('survey.legacy.end')
            ->with('status', $this->status);
    }
    dd('allright');
}
```

[image: Error Screenshot]

So Far I've no Idea how to fix this issue as cannot return the view directly in middleware, It has to be returned through my controller because of more business logic.

Please help me to understand and resolve this issue.

---

Update - Stacktrace in Logs

```
[2019-02-15 07:59:42] local.ERROR: Call to a member function setCookie() on null {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to a member function setCookie() on null at D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php:180)
[stacktrace]
#0 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php(77): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->addCookieToResponse(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#1 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\helpers.php(1027): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#2 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php(79): tap(Object(Illuminate\\View\\View), Object(Closure))
#3 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#4 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#5 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#6 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#7 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#8 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(63): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#9 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#10 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#11 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#12 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#14 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php(66): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#15 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#17 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(684): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#19 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(659): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(625): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#21 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(614): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#22 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#25 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(31): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#28 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#29 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#30 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(31): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#32 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#34 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#35 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#36 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(62): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#37 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#38 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#39 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#40 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#41 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#42 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\public\\index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#43 {main}
"}
```

Comment: What if you wrap your view in a response: return response(view('survey.legacy.end')
            ->with('status', $this->status));?, it is clearly something with the return type, and clearly somewhere you return null, or something is not the correct type.

Comment: I have lots of business logic after dd and I am returning view at various points, so it won't work for me

Comment: Give a stacktrace then, either it must hit the error view return or something in the middleware stack is wrong. Clearly no code after the dd gets hit, but you clearly have no idea what return statement that breaks the system.

Comment: @MartinHenriksen Just Added stacktrace from logs

Comment: As said it is a view that is passed as a response, wrap the view in a response. #0 D:\\xampp-new-installations\\xampp-7-2-4\\htdocs\\samppoint-new-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php(77): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->addCookieToResponse(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))

Comment: Ok, I am trying to do this now `return Response::view('survey.legacy.end', compact($status, $respstatus, $rowSurvey));` - but my view isn't able to find these passed variables, neither with `with()` nor `compact` any suggestions?

Comment: That is not how you use compact. try with return Response::view('survey.legacy.end', ['myvar' => $value]);

Comment: @MartinHenriksen Thanks, `return Response::view('survey.legacy.end', [ 'status' => $status, 'respstatus' => $respstatus, 'rowSurvey' => $rowSurvey ]);` resolved my problem.
Still, I couldn't understand why this has happened, I mean logic behind this issue. Can you create an answer with explanation?

Comment: Yes will do it in an hour or two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Laravel lifecycle sends your request through all middleware, what you are doing is actual replacing the current response with a new view. Only responses or request should be in this flow. This is an anti pattern and it is best to do a redirect. This will make laravels lifecycle try to run its middleware on a view and trying to set a cookie on it.

If you return a view wrapped with a response, it can now add a cookie to it. But you intercept the request response lifecycle in a hacky manner.

```
return Response::view('survey.legacy.end', [ 'status' => $status, 'respstatus' =>  $respstatus, 'rowSurvey' => $rowSurvey ]);
```