# Call to a member function setCookie() on null in middleware web

Tags: php, laravel

i used from modular structure in laravel that all module in Module folder that routes registerd in ModuleService provider with:

```
$this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/../Routes/web.php');
```

when i not use from middleware('web') in route then csrf token return null and when i use from this middleware then when user not logined and try to show dashboard page then show error:

```
Call to a member function setCookie() on null in middleware
```

Route

```
Route::get('account/dashboard', [StaffController::class, 'dashboard'])
->middleware(['web','staff'])->name('staff-dashboard');
```

middleware:staff

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class staff
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::guard('staff')->check() == false)
        {
            return view('staffauth::login');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**how to resolve this problem?**

Comment: see this answer if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54709213/10573560

Comment: seems you `staff` middleware is incorrect ... as it **must** return a response

Comment: @lagbox staff middleware aleady creared for check staff auth with staff guard

Comment: show that middleware

Comment: @lagbox question edited and add middleware

Comment: i would be redirecting them to the login route instead of returning a view, btw

Comment: @lagbox i test this solution but not resolved.

Comment: @lagbox when user request to open dashboard page from browser toolbar in the first step request send to web middleware and then send to staff middleware.
this problem in web middleware.