# Call to a member function setCookie() on null - Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, laravel-middleware

I have no idea why I keep getting this lately by just simply *navigate between pages.*

> Call to a member function setCookie() on null

[image]

This is what I have in my `AdminMiddleware`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Article;
use Closure, View, Auth ;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param  Guard  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ( Auth::user()->type !== "Admin") {
            return View::make('layouts.share.errors.404');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I'm on Laravel 5.8.

Comment: I did a quick reseach I found this answer. : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48970646/4480164

Comment: I suddenly check my AdminMiddleware since I logged in as `admin`, but nothing seems wrong in there, and I have no idea, why this is start happening - just *lately* - only.

Comment: Any **suggestions** on what should I look into will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error occurs when you are logged in as a non `Admin` because you are returning a `View` in your `AdminMiddleware` instead of a `Response`.

Replace:

```
if ( Auth::user()->type !== "Admin") {
    return View::make('layouts.share.errors.404');
}
```

With:

```
if ( Auth::user()->type !== "Admin") {
    return response()->view('layouts.share.errors.404', [], 404);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Chin Leung's answer and to properly return a 404 not found status code

```php
if ( Auth::user()->type !== "Admin") {
    return response()->view('layouts.share.errors.404', [], 404);
}
```